# Python:- what is meaning of "if(true)"

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to debug current code and I am new in python,
Need to understand below code
Why they use this code and Whats use of this code in python

```
def _init_():
  if(true):
```

Comment: `if True:` would be a means to block off a section of code so it can be turned on/off easily (since `if False:` is similar to a block comment). `if(true)` could hypothetically behave oddly if `true` is a Falsey variable.

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it

Comment: Besides the ability to switch a block quickly on and off, this idiom can also be used to group commands optically together.

Answer (score 2):

Before figuring out what `if(True)` does, think of `if(False)` first. `if(False)` is actually a commonly used idiom which has the same effect as commenting out multiple lines - all the code that's in its indentation block will not be executed since the condition is always evaluated as false. Later, if you want those lines of code below `if(False)` to be executed again, you can simply change False to True - that's how `if(True)` comes in. Itself doesn't do anything, it is its opposite `if(False)` that is useful.